# Count and display last 10 days data from SQL

Tags: php, sql, count

I am trying to create a small website, in which there is a referral system.
I want to display a user's last 10 days' referral counts.
Each day should be accessible separately.
For example, if today is 10th of January, the echo $day[9]; should display the total count which has the date January 10th in database.
I guess it will be something like following

```
SELECT username,COUNT(*)FROM reftable GROUP BY day(date)
```

I am able to get data in a table, but I want to access each day as $day[9]; or $day[8];  or $day[7];

How can I do that ?
The following is the best I was able to do so far, but I am not able to get individual day data (like $day[9]; or $day[8];  or $day[7];) from it.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

foreach($dbh->query('SELECT username,COUNT(*)
                    FROM reftable 
                    GROUP BY day(date)') as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're just missing either an order by, which will ensure that your row set appears in the order you expect:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) as theCount FROM reftable GROUP BY day(date) ORDER BY day(date)
```

Or you're not selecting the date so the front end can do the sorting/display the actual date to which the count refers:

```
SELECT day(date) as theDay, username, COUNT(*) as theCount FROM reftable GROUP BY day(date)
```

Or both of these

```
SELECT day(date) as theDay, username, COUNT(*) as theCount FROM reftable GROUP BY day(date) ORDER BY 1
```

Then you can eg

```
 echo "<td>" . $row['theDay'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['theCount'] . "</td>";
```

---

I'm puzzled as to why you don't have a `WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAYS` or similar, for pulling the last 10 days' data..

Comment: as I was just testing the code, I didn't bother to filter data by 10 days. can you please show me the rest of the code about how to select each data ? How can I use $day[9]; ?

Comment: Did I not do that with `$row['theDay']` ? (note that I'm not a php dev; i've just copied your pattern, so if you're wrong.. I'm wrong! :D but what you've written seems sensible..)

Comment: I dont know, I am still not able to make this working, let me try some other mays.